# Mapbox Ar does not work in all directions

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, augmented-reality

I have built an augmented reality application in Unity through Mapbox. Also, I geolocated some points through Mapbox. Points seems in AR in the application. But, I realized that when application is initialized the direction of the phone is important. It just shows the truth when phone follows the north.

I have some searched on internet, but I couldn't find any exact information.

I prefer to work application independently from phone direction. 
Can somebody explain that or are there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for would be [`Input.compass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-compass.html) → [`Compass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass.html) and in specific

[`Input.compass.magneticHeading`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass-magneticHeading.html)

> The heading in degrees relative to the magnetic North Pole. (Read Only)
>
> The value in this property is always measured relative to the top of the screen in its current orientation. The heading of magnetic north is not exactly the same as true geographical north - to get the exact heading, use the `trueHeading` property.

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Input.location.Start();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Orient an object to point to magnetic north.
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -Input.compass.magneticHeading, 0);
    }
}
```

or [`Input.compass.trueHeading`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass-trueHeading.html)

> The heading in degrees relative to the geographic North Pole. (Read Only)
>
> The value in this property is always measured relative to the top of the screen in its current orientation. **Note, that if you want this property to contain a valid value, you must also enable location updates by calling `Input.location.Start()`.** (Read Only)

Usage examples from the API

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Input.location.Start();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Orient an object to point northward.
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -Input.compass.trueHeading, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using `LocationProvider` of Mapbox. I checked it now and it is already using `Input.compass.trueHeading`. I understand that we can't do this automatically. It always top of the screen in its current orientation. So, the user must rotate the screen to the north. Is it right ?

Comment: No you could also store the offset between north and the smartphone rotation and later use this offset to position your objects relative to the camera orientation

Comment: Oh and I just found it in the docs of `MapBox`: Do you use the `Rotate With Location Provider` component?