# What is the size limit of the gameobjects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, augmented-reality

I am building an AR application with unity and Mapbox. I have a point to represents a building. I can geolocate the point through Mapbox. I want to see this object everywhere. So, I change the size of objects according to distance.

Firstly, the code is working. But, I could not see the point really far away, 5 km away.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Get user location
    // Latitude
    x = getLocation.x1.ToString();
    user_lat = Convert.ToDouble(x);
    user_lat_rad = Math.PI * user_lat / 180.0; // Radian
    // Longitude
    y = getLocation.y1.ToString();
    user_lon = Convert.ToDouble(y);
    user_lon_rad = Math.PI * user_lon / 180.0; // Radian
    // Change POIs sizes
    distances = distance(user_lat_rad, user_lon_rad);
    double s = 0.3; // size of the poi
    double d = 50f; // specific distance to point (reference distance)
    double size = (distances * s) / d;
    float size2 = Convert.ToSingle(size);
    temp = transform.localScale;
    temp.x = size2;
    temp.y = size2;
    temp.z = size2;
    transform.localScale = temp;
}
public double distance(double lat2, double lon2)
{
    // Haversine Formula
    // Lat2,Lon2 = User Location
    // Lat1,Lon1 = POI Location
    double dist1 = Sqrt((Pow(Sin((lat2 - lat1) / 2), 2)) + Cos(lat2) * Cos(lat2) * (Pow(Sin((lon2 - lon1) / 2), 2)));
    double distance = 2 * r * Asin(dist1);
    return distance;
}
```

Why I couldn't see the point far away even though object size is change? Is there any limitation for this?

Comment: should probably be [`float.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.maxvalue) but did you check the [Camera's](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) [Far clipping plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-farClipPlane.html)? Don't know how you translate Unity units into meters/kilometers but afaik the default for the Far clip plane is `1000` units

Comment: I understood what happened and also it worked thanks!

Comment: Would u mind answer this question, if u know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645448/mapbox-ar-does-not-work-in-all-directions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments the issue most probably is a too small value for the [`Camera's`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) [`farClipPlane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-farClipPlane.html).

> The furthest point relative to the camera that drawing will occur.

Any object/triangle that is further away from the `Camera` will not be rendered.

---

In the Inspector it is configured on the `Camera` component → `Clipping Planes` → `Far`

[image]

or using code

```
cameraReference.farClipPlane = XYZ;
```